# How do add a "Create a readme" button in Windows 7 explorer, similar to "Create a folder"?

Tags: windows, button, explorer, regedit

I would like do add a "Create a readme.txt" button in Windows 7 explorer, similar to "Create a folder" ?
This button would create a blank readme.txt in the current folder.

This image is in french, but I'm sure you'll understand it!

[image: New readme.txt]

Comment: Maybe you should ask this question on superuser.com instead

Comment: thanks @ert! is there a move to "superuser.com"  feature in stackoverflow?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it's possible to add this kind of action. All you can do is described here:

http://www.askvg.com/explorer-toolbar-editor-free-utility-to-customize-windows-explorer-command-bar-aka-folder-band-or-toolbar-in-windows-7/

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/use-special-codes-to-add-commands-to-the-windows-explorer-command-bar/3753

Comment: so sad! are you 100% sure it's impossible? i'd love to have this feature!